Unable to boot into Ubuntu 22.04.05, black screen appears with this text: /dev/nvme0n1p4: [random no] clean, [random no] files/ blocks
I am using a dual boot system with windows 11 and linux ( for approx 5 months now).
Some info:
Host: Asus TUF F15 FX507ZC4
OS : Ubuntu 22.04.05 LTS x86_64
Kernel : 6.8.0-40-generic
Shell: bash 5.1.16
RAM: 15612MB (16GB)
Problem:
I installed a game on my windows 11 last night (more context is given in next section). After playing

restart laptop


grub menu appears, clicks on ubuntu


black screen appears with this text:
/dev/nvme0n1p4: [some random no] clean, [random no] files/ blocks


the black screen disappears after a minute, and ubuntu logo appears, with loading circle


it keeps on loading for more than 10 minutes (average loading time is 30seconds) so obviously something is wrong

This now happens everytime I try to load ubuntu and I'm unable to use it.
I also tried some solutions of similar problems on askubuntu but none of them solved my problem. If someone can guide me, I'll list all the details of what I've tried till now.
Some background:
A week ago, I was losing a lot of battery when my pc was on sleep in ubuntu, so i tried to enable hibernate option. One answer on askubuntu suggested to increase the swap memory size, I followed the instructions given, but wasn't able to enable hibernate option.
It required me to have swap memory twice the size of RAM, which is 16GB. So I searched for a way to do it without swap memory. And that was with the help of a swap file. I followed a tutorial, but i abandoned it in middle because it required me to tinker with some stuff i had no idea about.
Also, on my windows 11, I installed Batman Arkham Asylum from steam on the day i faced this problem. I had to install .NET framework, which i did, but then i came acroas an error which was solved by this solution i found on steam community for the game :
Go to steamapps>common>batman arkham asylum goty>redist>directx
then just run "DXSETUP"
After running DXSETUP, i was able to run the game.

So nobody answered my question, and none of the solutions available on the internet that I came across worked. So I booted into windows, removed grub bootloader, then deleted the partition on which ubuntu was installed. Then reinstalled ubuntu.
